# Django always gives 404

Tags: django

My Django project always gives me a 404, no matter what page I'm trying to visit. Being a Django noob, I have no idea how to troubleshoot this. Any suggestions?

Edit: here's my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^mcifdjango/', include('mcifdjango.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Nothing. I have to idea how to troubleshoot the problem, so I haven't tried to troubleshoot it.

Comment: turn on Debug mode and paste the entire 404 urls attempted message.

Comment: Being new to django myself, I'd strongly suggest working through the tutorials here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/  It'll explain the urls.py file, and tells you pretty much everything you need to know to get started.  It'll walk you through setting up your first basic app.  After knowing the basics the rest of the documentation becomes more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include a mapping from urls to views in your urls.py. For more information:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 3):

What kind of behavior were you expecting?

You have no urls mapped to anything -- you **should** only be getting 404s!

```
import http

def a_view(request):
    return http.HttpResponse("My first mapped url")

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', a_view), # my first url mapped to anything
    (r'^second_url/$', a_view), # my second non 404 url
)
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what I was expecting anywhere else, but when I went to `/admin`, I was expecting to see the admin login screen. markijbema prompted me to look at `urls.py` and I saw there that I had to uncomment some stuff in order to enable the admin, and now the admin seems to work. I get the login screen, at least.